# JWT gem - retrieve public signing key from remote authority URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have:

- An OpenID Connect identity / token server written in AspNet 6
- A resource API that I want to protect with access tokens from the identity server, writen in Ruby / Rails

The issued tokens are assymetrically (public/private key) signed JWTs.

If I was writing the resource API in .Net, I would provide a URI for the token authority when setting up authentication, e.g.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions() {
    Authority = "https://uri.to.my.identity.server"
}
```

The JWT bearer authentication middleware would use this URI to find and retrieve the public key from the identity server, so that it can be used to validate token signatures.

I am looking for a similar approach when using the Ruby JWT gem (https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)

The RSA example on that site just provides the public key explicitly, e.g.

```
rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key
decoded_token = JWT.decode token, rsa_public, true, { algorithm: 'RS256' }
```

I could call the identity server discovery endpoint directly, but I was hoping there might be something part of the library (or another library) that would help with this.